# How to insert <hr/> tags between posts in Wordpress for Themantic theme

Tags: wordpress, post, line, each

I have been trying to insert `<hr/>` tags posts in Wordpress blog. How can I do that such that there is no `<hr/>` tag after the last post?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$args = array('YOUR_QUERY_ARGS');
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$i=1;
if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <!-- YOUR POSTS HERE -->
<?php
    echo $i==$query->found_posts ? '' : '<hr/>';
    $i++;
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

I would highly recommend using [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in place of query_posts() if you aren't already.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a check like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$i++;
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];

    if ($i == $num_rows)    
                break;

    echo '<hr>';
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```